# Mass Assignment error with SIngle Table inheritance situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

I'm setting up a contacts module and basically am setting it up so a contact can have unlimited contact details i.e x phone numbers, emails, addresses etc. I've set up two different table shere one is for the contacts base details and the other one holds just contact details such as:

```
Contact
NAME|DETAILS|COUNTRY ....

ContactDetails
TYPE|LOCATION|DETAILS
enter code here
```

where type can be Phone, Fax, Email and location can be 'work', 'official', 'direct' and details is the actual number or email.

I initially set up a contact_details model and later on thought of setting up different models for each contact_detail such as a model called phone, fax and email and each would inherit from contact_details.

Here are my current models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_citier
  attr_accessible :about, :name, :type

  has_many :contact_details

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_details

end

class Company < Contact
  attr_accessible :company_name, :description, :timezone, :website, :twenty_four_ops, :type
  acts_as_citier
  before_save :set_parent_attributes
####  
end

# this is the contact etail which corresponds to either a phone, email or fax etc
class ContactDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contact_id, :type, :details, :location

  belongs_to :contact
end

The phone and fax classes

class Phone < ContactDetail

end

class Fax < ContactDetail

end
```

I set up a form using the nested forms tutorial on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast), basically my form however is for entering a COMPANY object which is a child of the Contact class. The contact details are associated with teh contact class so I'm assuming that if a contact has contact details so a company which is a child of contact sshould also have contact details. My form is set up pretty ok however when I submit the form I get a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: contact_details_attributes error.`

I'm not too sure with whats going wrong here - I've set up the attributes_accessible as they should be in the code above - whats missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried, accepts_nested_attributes  in the company class? Or adding contact_details_attributes to your attr_accessible list in the base class

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a reserved attribute in activerecord. You can still use it by setting

```
self.inheritance_column = :kind # or provide another name
```

Comment: I know that and I was trying to leverage it basically Phone inherits from contact details base class